# how to record a video with audio from a game session - Android smartphone?

Tags: android, audio, video, javafx, recording

I wish to capture a video and audio sequence of this video game for including it in a web site.

The adb tool can only record the video (without audio). And some recording tools (freeware or not) provide the same restriction.

So, how to record a video with its synchronized audio of a video game session on Android smartphone?

Thanks

Note: the audio signal must be **internally** catched for guaranteeing a good quality (no external capture from the microphone)

Comment: You could write a background service to capture the default audio output stream.

Comment: benardier: OK, but what is the dedicated method and class to do that with JavaFX? And, after I should synchronize the recorded (stored) audio with the recorded video, isn't it?